# How can I use enumerate function in Python?

Tags: python

```
for num, data in enumerate(test_data[:len(test_data)]):
```

I have a code snippet like this. Let's say I have 30 data, in the test data.
Is this for loop goes from 0 to 30 or from 0 to 29?

Comment: How could it go to 30? There are only 30 elements in the list, but 0 to 30 would iterate 31 times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 0 to 29:

```
>>> test_data = [n for n in range(0,30)]
>>> for num, data in enumerate(test_data[:len(test_data)]):
...   print(num)
... 
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test it by printing the count.

```
for i in range(0,4):
    print(i)
```

Output:

`0 1 2 3`

Comment: You don't have a list slice, so this answer doesn't really help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).